# Resigning a xamarin android apk using apksigner fails

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

after having generated a signed apk using archive/adhoc distribute and installed it on a device it works fine.

But when i resign the signed apk using apksigner.bat (from android sdk) using the same keystore and deploy it on a device, the app won't launch.

Adb log:

```
W/monodroid(12082): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/com.company.TSMClient-1/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(12082): No assemblies found in '(null)' or '<unavailable>'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
I/ActivityManager(21181): Process com.company.TSMClient (pid 12082) has died.
```

I checked inside the apk for diff and found that in the META-INF folder the resigned apk has slightly smaller .RSA and .SF files.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue did manage to get the app to launch in the end?

Comment: Yes: I activated multidex and updated pro guard in the android sdk.

Comment: To update pro guard, replace the existing folder content with the zip you downloaded from the sourceforge site.

Comment: Sweet that worked for me too cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it this way:

- I activated multidex and updated pro guard in the android sdk
- To update pro guard, replace the existing folder content with the zip you downloaded from the sourceforge site

Please also vote up for Xamarin issue https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44187